# rbenv 2.2.1 cannot install, complains on bundler (>= 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

Im not able to install rbenv version 2.2.1, please help, what could be the issue ?

```
axil-Pro:~ megasap$ rbenv install 2.2.1
rbenv: /Users/axil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1 already exists
continue with installation? (y/N) y
Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5a4de38068eca8919cb087d338c0c2e3d72c9382c804fb27ab746e6c7819ab28
Installing ruby-2.2.1...
Installed ruby-2.2.1 to /Users/axil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler\n' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: bundle_rc, bundler08, bundler-fu, bundler, bundler-pgs
rbenv: error installing gem `bundler\n'
```

I am using OS X El Capitan - 10.11.1

Comment: This is the issue: `Could not find a valid gem 'bundler\n' (>= 0) in any repository` you might want to run ``gem install bundler``

Comment: @Abhinay tqvm for you reply. Still the same problem. Any troubleshooting ideas I can try ? here is the printouts trying gem install bundler and then rbenv install 2.2.1 https://gist.github.com/survivaltravel/b3190b30510b92f7a3cd

Comment: `gem sources -r https://rubygems.org -a http://rubygems.org` try running this command. see if this solves the issue.

Comment: makes no sense to need bundler to install a ruby

Answer (score 0):

in .rbenv/default-gems contains this one line "bundler\n"

remove \n did the trick

Thanks!